# How to show json data in label?

Tags: json, swift, label

I have a few label and I got data from json. I want to show json data in label. What should I do? I can get data from webservice and I can print in terminal, but I can not send this datas my labels.

My labels;

```
@IBOutlet weak var lblYearlyProfit: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lblTotalProfit: UILabel!
```

My json function and this is successfuly.

```
func getSales(authorization:String){


    let url = NSURL(string: "http://api.xxx.com/salesreport")

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)

    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    request.addValue(authorization, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data,response,error in

        guard error == nil && data != nil else {
            print("error", error!)
            return
        }

        let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse

        if httpStatus!.statusCode == 200
        {
            if data?.count != 0
            {
                let responString = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSArray

                print(responString!, "get sales successful")

                // i can not do anything in here.

                DispatchQueue.main.async{
                }
            }

            else{
                print("No got data from URL")
            }
        }

        else{

            print("error httpstatus code is ", httpStatus!.statusCode)

        }
    }

    task.resume()

}
```

I am waiting your help?

Comment: Parse your json.

Comment: can you provide your response json, and which data you want to display on label.?

Comment: Plz Send your json response like data then I will tell us. @C.Sayin

Comment: {
    "dailyCiro": "0,00 TL",
    "monthlyCiro": "374,82 TL",
    "yearlyCiro": "282.945,45 TL",
    "totalCiro": "1.864.549,71 TL",
    "dailyKazanc": "0,00 TL",
    "monthlyKazanc": "186,96 TL",
    "yearlyKazanc": "86.593,87 TL",
    "totalKazanc": "684.976,28 TL"
  }

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that because it's completion block or you haven't parsed it to string. Just use `self` before label name and cast your response to String